# Given a date and get the beginning date of previous month using lubridate package

Tags: r, date, lubridate

Given any date, I use this code to get the beginning date of previous month from that date:

```
library(lubridate)

end_date <- '2021-10-30'
floor_date(as.Date(end_date) - months(1), 'month')
[1] "2021-09-01"
```

But I've found it return `NA`, as the format of date is `%Y-%m-31`:

```
end_date <- '2021-10-31'
floor_date(as.Date(end_date) - months(1), 'month')
[1] NA
```

How could we explain this error?

Comment: I guess it's because there is no 31st of September. Try with `'2021-08-31'`, it works well.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think so, if you check: https://www.wincalendar.com/Calendar/Date/October-31-2021

Comment: It seems not answer my question from the link you provided, since the error comes from not how to get the first day, but previous month @Limey

Comment: Your error is explained by the fact that `as.Date(2021-10-31) - months(1)` would return `2021-09-31` but since this day does not exist it returns NA.

Comment: The 31st of the month is not guaranteed to exist.  But the 1st of each month is.  So reverse the order of operations to ensure you have a valid date at each stage:  `lubridate::floor_date(as.Date(end_date), "month") - months(1)`, as suggested by @Waldi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could substract the month after `floor`:

```
end_date <- '2021-10-31'
floor_date(as.Date(end_date), 'month') - months(1)

[1] "2021-09-01"
```